# I faced the perl problem which says you may need to install the inc::Module::Install module

Tags: perl

my OS is Ubuntu 20.04, and i installed perl with keys

```
apt-get install libdbd-mysql-perl -y
apt-get install libconfig-tiny-perl -y
apt-get install libparams-validate-perl -y
apt-get install libparallel-forkmanager-perl -y
apt-get install liblog-dispatch-perl -y
apt-get install libtime-hires-perl -y
apt-get install make -y
apt-get install libnet-telnet-perl -y
apt-get install libdbd-mysql-perl libconfig-tiny-perl libparams-validate-perl libparallel-forkmanager-perl liblog-dispatch-perl libtime-hires-perl make
```

I can find that perl is installed through 'perl --version' says

```
This is perl 5, version 30, subversion 0 (v5.30.0) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
(with 50 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)

Copyright 1987-2019, Larry Wall

Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License or the
GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5 source kit.

Complete documentation for Perl, including FAQ lists, should be found on
this system using "man perl" or "perldoc perl".  If you have access to the
Internet, point your browser at http://www.perl.org/, the Perl Home Page.
```

I want to install mha4mysql-manager and node that i could download it from https://github.com/yoshinorim/mha4mysql-node/releases/tag/v0.58.  I installed do perl Makefile.PL, but it says

```
Can't locate inc/Module/Install.pm in @INC (you may need to install the inc::Module::Install module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30.0 /usr/local/share/perl/5.30.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.30 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30 /usr/share/perl/5.30 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base) at Makefile.PL line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Makefile.PL line 1.
```

Comment: Do you really want to use this module? It's unmaintained and apparently unfinished. Note the number of issues and pull requests in the github repo. Also, your issue was reported as [#26](https://github.com/yoshinorim/mha4mysql-node/pull/26). Always check the existing issues to see if someone has already had the same problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

This module uses [`Module::Install`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Module-Install/lib/Module/Install/FAQ.pod), so you need to install it first:

```sh
sudo apt-get install libmodule-install-perl
```

Most Perl modules are packaged for Ubuntu or Debian, so it's usually faster (and saves installation time) to look up the equivalent distro package and install it directly.

Comment: Although the _Makefile.PL_ uses Module::Install, the distribution apparently does not include it. `cpan` won't be able to get around that. That's why he gets that error. I'm not sure what you are linking to in those pointers to the docs, or why you think `cpan` would work.

Comment: @briandfoy I thought it looked up everything that was used in Makefile.PL and install it. That does not seem to be the case. Editing.

Comment: It can't look up things in _Makefile.PL_ if it can't run it.